# jQuery - if parent has not class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to create auto-add class to DIV, so I do:

```
$( '.navigation' ).find( 'li.active' ).parents( 'li' ).addClass( 'active' );
```

It's works great! But now I need to 'ignore' parents if has, eg. 'dropdown-toggle' so I modified this for:

```
$( '.navigation' ).find( 'li.active' ).parents( 'li:not(.dropdown-toggle)' ).addClass( 'active' );
```

But that's not working - where is my bad?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: How about `$( '.navigation' ).find( 'li.active' ).parents( 'li' ).not('.dropdown-toggle').addClass( 'active' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `parents()` with `:not` like :

```
$('.navigation li.active').parents('li:not(".dropdown-toggle")').addClass('active');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.navigation li.active').parents('li:not(".dropdown-toggle")').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='navigation'>
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li class='active'>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li class='dropdown-toggle'>Coffee (Has dropdown-toggle class)
    <ul>
      <li>Black Coffee</li>
      <li class='active'>Cream Coffee</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```